# Find indexes of elements in list that is approximatly equal to element in another list

Tags: python, list, debugging, floating-point, subtraction

I have 2 lists with floating point numbers:

```
list_1 = [1.03, 3.56, 4.91, 2.85, 5.55, 1.12, 1.73, 1.33, 2.56, 2.58, 3.53]
list_2 = [1.05, 1.55, 2.05, 2.55, 3, 3.55, 4]
```

The goal is to compare 2 lists and return the indexes of element from the first list (`list_1`) if they are approximatly equal based on the specific threshold.

```
def compare_lists(list1, list2, threshold=0.02):
    output_list = []
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        for j in range(len(list2)):
            print(abs(list1[i] - list2[j]))
            if abs(list1[i] - list2[j]) <= threshold:
                output_list.append(i)
    return output_list
```

This is only return `[1, 8]` that I think it is wrong. There are some indexes should be included in the output list such as 0 and the last one.

I think the problem is the subtraction of the floating points. I checked the difference between 1.03 and 1.05 and it returns  `0.02000000000000018`

How can I fix this problem? or I just could round them, but this is not a good choice because the list can contain varied decimal points. It doesn't scope just 2 points, as well as the threshold.

Comment: The output list that contains the correct indexes that they suppose to be.

Comment: What is your expected output for the two lists given? Please edit your post to contain this information.

Comment: if you want to specify the threshold to 0.02 then just round the absolute difference to two decimal places. It would essentially be equivalent to @python_user suggestion

Comment: @2293980990 I don't know, would that solve the problem? `round(x - y, 2)` is still a float, and the machine might not store that as the exact number `0.02`, which again would lead to the same problem. I'm not sure, though :)

Comment: I'm far from an expert on the dangers of floating point errors, but see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) , specifically the part on the usefulness of post-rounding.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have more padding, due to round-off error:

```py
list_1 = [1.03, 3.56, 4.91, 2.85, 5.55, 1.12, 1.73, 1.33, 2.56, 2.58, 3.53]
list_2 = [1.05, 1.55, 2.05, 2.55, 3, 3.55, 4]

output = [i for i, x in enumerate(list_1) for y in list_2 if abs(x - y) <= 0.02 + 1e-8]
print(output) # [0, 1, 8, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has the `decimal` module https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html "for fast correctly-rounded decimal floating point arithmetic".

```py
from decimal import Decimal

list_1 = [1.03, 3.56, 4.91, 2.85, 5.55, 1.12, 1.73, 1.33, 2.56, 2.58, 3.53]
list_2 = [1.05, 1.55, 2.05, 2.55, 3, 3.55, 4]

def compare_lists(list1, list2, threshold=0.02):
    threshold = Decimal(str(threshold))
    list2 = [Decimal(str(y)) for y in list2]

    output_list = []
    for i, x in enumerate(list1):
        x = Decimal(str(x))
        if any(abs(x-y) <= threshold for y in list2):
            output_list.append(i)
    return output_list

print(compare_lists(list_1, list_2))  # prints [0, 1, 8, 10]
```